# Retrieving information to display using NSUserDefaults using swift

Tags: xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to take information the a user puts in on one page and post it on another. Right now I have a registerviewController where the user puts in the information and I store it using NSUserDefaults. What I want to know is how to take that stored information and put it on the viewController page.

Code I have so far:

On register view controller:

```
let name = userName.text;
        let student = userStudent.text;
        let gender = userGender.text;
        let username = userUsername.text;
        let password = userPassword.text;
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(name, forKey:"name");
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(student, forKey:"student");
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(gender, forKey:"gender");
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(username, forKey:"username");
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(password, forKey:"password");
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
```

View controller:
(this is code I found that said it should work but nothing is showing when i run the program)

```
if let name = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("name"){
        print (name);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I save object in `UserDefaults` like this:

```
NSUserDefaults().setObject(student, forKey: "student")
```

and get your object:

```
if let name = NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("student") as? String {
    print(name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ValueForKey for get user default value

```
//Define user default
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

//Set value
self.userDefaults.setObject("data", forKey: "Key")
self.userDefaults.synchronize()

//Get value
if let name = self.userDefaults.valueForKey("Key"){
    print(name)
}

//Remove value
self.userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("Key")
```